# unity make a character controller "shove" other character controllers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so hey guy, I have a rather basic problem yet I couldn't find out how to.

I am using a character controller as a player, and that player will move around using something like this:

```
con.Move (transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

now, my problem apparently this character controller cannot push other character controllers, it just get stuck in front of it.

so far, I tried this code :

```
void OnControllerColliderHit (ControllerColliderHit hit) {
        CharacterController con = hit.transform.GetComponent<CharacterController> ();

        if (con == null) {return;}
        if (hit.moveDirection.y < -0.3F) {return;}

        Vector3 pushDir = new Vector3 (hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);
        con.Move (pushDir * Time.deltaTime * pushSpeed);
    }
```

well it works, but it has some kind of jitter/shaking problem while being pushed, and it doesn't look so good.

Is there any other way? I don't want to use Unity Physics/Rigidbody as it is not needed.

Comment: The easiest way is it to just move the colliding GameObject in a direction of angle of direction of your player and the hit gameobject. I hope I say it correctly. From the hit object you can get the angle. By move I mean "transform.position".

Comment: true, but it is exactly what my above code do, angle of direciton is the variable pushDir I believe, and transform.position will just replace con.Move (), it still has the same 'shaky' problem

Comment: Why would you not want to use a rigidbody? This problem could be solved really easily if you used them?

Comment: isn't rigidbody and charactercontroller kind of not fit together? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html
my characters movement is like of a doom-style game, with no need of acceleration or deceleration